# How to Convert sympy.Float to decimal.Decimal without trap?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, decimal, sympy

Consider the following expression in sympy

```
(sp.Float(3000)**20000)**20000
```

or, equivalently, in decimal,

```
(Decimal(3000)**20000)**20000
```

which was approximately

```
Decimal('7.72440390834123481997707091832E+1390848501')
```

However, the conversion between the sympy.Float and decimal.Decimal is not supported

```
Decimal((sp.Float(3000)**20000)**20000)
TypeError: conversion from Float to Decimal is not supported
```

and if using a float function in between,

```
Decimal(float( (sp.Float(3000)**20000)**20000))
```

the value would be wrongly converted as

```
Decimal('Infinity')
```

because the number was larger than the float's limit.

How to Convert sympy.Float to decimal.Decimal without trap?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert via str:

```
In [6]: from decimal import Decimal

In [7]: from sympy import Float

In [8]: f = (Float(3000)**20000)**20000

In [9]: Decimal(str(f))
Out[9]: Decimal('7.72440390834144E+1390848501')
```

Comment: This will not work if the working precision is not set high enough. You will get an `InvalidOperation` error. If you try `Decimal('7.72440390834144E+139084850')` (notice that the exponent has the last digit missing) and it works, you will know this is the issue and can investigate how to set the precision higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired precision for a Decimal number like

```py
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100 # can't be bigger than MAX_PREC
>>> MAX_PREC
425000000
```

Your exponent is bigger than MAX_PREC so you won't be able to represent it with Decimal unless you can make MAX_PREC bigger. Have you considered storing the logarithm of your number instead of the number itself?